# complementary subspaces/involutory matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be a vector space, $A:V\to V$ a linear application for which the associated matrix satisfies $A²=I$ (involutory matrix).

Prove that $V_1= \{x \in V|\ A(x)= x\}$ and $V_2= \{x \in V|\ A(x)= - x\}$ are complementary subspaces of $V$, ie, $V=V_1+V_2$ and $V_1 \cap V_2= \{0\}$.

Comment: No, in $V_2$ you overlooked the little "-".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: every vector $x$ can be written as $x=\frac{1}{2}(x+Ax)+\frac{1}{2}(x-Ax)$. One of the summands is in $V_1$ the other in $V_2$ (which is in which?). This shows $V_1+V_2=V$. $V_1\cap V_2=\{0\}$ should be easy.